# Cypher Where IN ['GUID', 'GUID'] in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find nodes in Neo4j Db by Guid from my object.

I have 'Id' field in my object, which is Guid.
Need to find several nodes by those Guid Id, but when I use Where clause and use IN command with array of Guid Id's I get response, that (no changes, no records)

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.Id IN ['44BEE918-507A-15C6-0950-0017D4A12234', 'BC2D286F-0B73-6926-B01D-27C8F0EA919D'] RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

I tried to pass Guids without quotes and with double quotes, but it didn't help.
When I pass the Name of those nodes it works perfect.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I found an issue. The problem was with case sensitivity. Means my Guid in the database looks like '44bee918-507a-15c6-0950-0017d4a12234', but I tried to find in upper case.

Comment: Please either delete the question or post your answer as a proper answer, so that this question can be properly closed. Posting your answer as a comment doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue.
The problem was with case sensitivity. Means my Guid in the database looks like '44bee918-507a-15c6-0950-0017d4a12234', but I tried to find in upper case.